# Jquery does not execute a css command before an ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I wrote a simple code that loops over several items in the DOM and adds them to the CART via an AJAX call.

The problem is that an animation that should be shown at the beginning of the action is not shown in Chrome (in Firefox it's ok!).

**This is the code:**

```
 $(document).on('click','.btn_add_cart', function() {

   $("#wait").css('opacity',1); //starts an animation

   $(".one_item").each(function(index, value) {

        var post_data = {
          //some post data
        };
        $.ajax({                    
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/ajax/Add_to_cart",
            data: post_data,                      
            success: function(res){
            //do some code
            }

        });         

   })

   //stop the animation
})
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you please check the error once in the console.

Comment: Is there anything after the `//stop the animation` comment, like `$("#wait").css('opacity',0);`?

Answer (score 1):

$(document).on('click','.btn_add_cart', function() {

$("#wait").css('opacity',1); //starts an animation

setTimeout(function() {

```
var flag = 0;
```

$(".one_item").each(function(index, value) {

```
    var post_data = {
      flag = 1;
    };
    $.ajax({                    
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/ajax/Add_to_cart",
        data: post_data,                      
        success: function(res){
        //do some code
        }

    });
```

});

```
     if(flag == 1) {
      //stop the animation
      $("#wait").css('opacity',0); 

    } 
  }
```

}, 1000);

})